# Модератор удаляет описание

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Вы поняли о чем речь? Нет? Я тоже.

Тем не менее, мы можем это увидеть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/574171/revisions):

[image: Модератор удаляет описание]

На [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262662?key=5ac3422e3746b356d22756dfd32c58cf) оригинал выглядит так:

> Mod Removes Wiki

Предпосылки к этому действию описаны в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32739394#32739394).

Давайте вместе придумаем, как же фраза должна звучать по-русски.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Статус «общего» убран** участником {{NAME}}

Этот вариант основан на интерфейсе: галочку "общий" много кто видел, даже не пользовавшись ею раньше.

Comment: «отменён модератором {{NAME}}»?

Comment: @VladD "участником" как я понимаю, другая строка. Предложите своим вариантом!

Comment: Если этот вариант будет принят, следует заменить двойные кавычки согласно руководству по переводу на `«»`.

Comment: @alexolut Да, такой и используется.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а может ли не модератор убрать статус "общего"? Если нет, то "участник" тут не совсем корректно.

Comment: @alexolut не может. Ну, модераторы тоже участники, чего ж нет. А расположение строк позволяет подправить этот момент только в этом пояснении?

Comment: @D-side совсем забыл, что `участником` это другая строка. В английской версии вместо "участника" вообще `by` :)

Comment: @alexolut можно сделать ход конём: сделать её пустой строкой и добавить в сообщения как надо. :)

Comment: @D-side не думаю, что это получится, т.к. общая строка (если я не путаю) `**$historyType$** by $userLink$` используется в разных контекстах. Т.е. `участником` всё же потребуется.

Comment: @alexolut Не модератор может убрать статус «общего» у своего сообщения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky разве? Мне казалась в справке написано, что это может делать только модератор.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [не может](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/318749).

Comment: Может быть @NicolasChabanovsky имеет в виду себя (т.к. его нет в [списке модераторов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)) :-D

Comment: @alexolut это [мало что означает](http://i.imgur.com/lfnZufX.png)...

Answer (score 5):

Вариант из комментариев под ответом уважаемого @D-side:

> **Возвращено авторство** участником {{NAME}}

Comment: Я бы, наверное, поменял первые слова местами, лучше звучит что ли. И несколько неочевидно **чьё** авторство. Последнее мне видится сложной проблемой.

Comment: Авторство автора очевидно.

Comment: Может быть. Я это скорее оцениваю, как "угадывается", но не "уверенность". Посмотрим на поддержку среди остальных. Я допускаю, что могу быть неправ.

Comment: @D-side не обязательно нужно быть правым, главное быть первым.

Answer (score 4):

Не удержался :)

> [модераторский-произвол](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb) участника PashaPash.

Answer (score 2):

> **Возвращено автору в собственность** участником {{NAME}}

Comment: Что-то я не уверен, что пост есть собственность автора. Он его даже удалить не может окончательно.

Comment: @alexolut не любую информацию можно удалить отовсюду. Автор сообщения передаёт права на распространение без изменений **с указанием авторства** при публикации. Что он удаляет, SO по-прежнему имеет право распространять хоть из собственных архивных копий. Уместнее было бы, наверное, говорить о **возвращении авторства**, но я пока не очень представляю, как это ужать в небольшую фразу без тавтологии.

Comment: Так может `Возвращено авторство`?

Comment: @alexolut опубликуйте -- узнаем.

Comment: Можно голосовать!